# How to change width of expandable "+" column?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am use antd Table with expandRow. Tried different styles, but they break neighboring cells. It didn't work out. there is nothing in the documentation on this issue.

I want to reduce the size of the column in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvapQ.png .
Help me, please.

Comment: You can use `expandable` prop and set `columnWidth` like this: `<Table expandable={{ columnWidth: 100 }} />`. You can follow [Antd Expandable](https://ant.design/components/table#expandable) api for all available options.

Comment: but then the plus icon inside is not in the center, and there is no way to align

Comment: Use `expandIcon` to customize the icon